# how to find the number of occurence of a particular word from text file in unix

Tags: unix

I have a text file in which i have 17000 lines, example:

```
another instance started
another instance started
instance not started
bss instance started
```

like this.

I have to find the number of times the word 'another' is in printed in the above example my output should be 2.  I need shell script command for the above example.  Can any one help me with shell coding or command?

Comment: Please add what you have tried. Most people want to help, not do your work

Comment: sorry i am new to unix so i did not try anything i need answers to try out with and will try to improve my skills based on answers

Comment: There is nothing wrong with being new.  But try searching before asking.  Google is your friend.  It'll improve the odds that you're next question will be up voted.  Hope we helped.  Feel free to accept an answer.

Comment: Thank u for your positive answer i will try and post my doubts after i try

Answer (score 2):

First you should try to search harder, the answer can be found easily.

Second:

```
grep -c another yourfilepath
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use good old grep.

```
grep -c 'word' file
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep -c flip article.txt`

10

See http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2384

and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

```
\<another\> is a word boundary and it won't match abcanother or anotherxyz etc.

grep -o '\<another\>' file.txt | wc -l
```